# Update BIOS on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, bios

I am using a HP 15 laptop running Ubuntu and am trying to find BIOS for my hardware. The current version is 2013, its strange and unfair that HP thinks people only use Windows.

Is there a way i can possibly extract files from the exe file available for the Windows system and update my BIOS to 2016 ?

Comment: This is something you should [ask HP](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/How-do-I-update-the-BIOS-in-Linux/td-p/6498633). (the accepted answer below should help).

Comment: or see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/539120/how-to-perform-a-hp-bios-upgrade-with-only-ubuntu

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I had tried HP forum link before posting here and unfortunately the second suggestion didn't work for me.

Comment: try installing win10 and then delete it after BIOS update .... https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10